# Comment dirais-je ?

Tags: sens, expressions, usage, prononciation

Quand peut-on employer

> Comment dirais-je ?

Quelle est la correcte prononciation ?

Il me semble que j'ai entendu

> Comment en dirais-je ?

Cette variante existe-t-elle ?

Comment: jamais entendu la variante..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Comment dirais-je* /komɑ̃.diʁɛʒ/ is used as an *[incise](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/incise)* in formal French to allow the speaker to find a right word or expression in the meantime, e.g. :

> *Ce film est, comment dirais-je, un navet.* (This movie is, how shall I put it, a turkey)

Standard/colloquial French just use *[euh](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/euh)*...

*Comment en dirais-je* can be used in a sentence like:

> *Comment en dirais-je du mal ?* (How would I say bad things about it/him/her/them?)

Comment: Merci. Dans la variante avec en, ce dernier que'est-ce que remplace ?

Comment: En plus comment on la prononce correctement ? Il me semble entendre diraij, non ?

Comment: *En* remplace son antécédent...

Comment: En peut remplacer personnes ?

Comment: *De lui, d'elle, d'eux, d'elles* sont plus courants (*Comment dirais-je du mal d'eux*) mais *en* peut parfois remplacer des personnes, par exemple aussi dans: *Des grecs, j'en ai rencontré plusieurs.*

Comment: Parfait. +1. Merci beaucoup.

Comment: C'est bien la prononciation; il n'y a pas d'exceptions; le e ne se prononce pas.@dimitris

Comment: Le *e* final est muet mais peut se prononcer dans le sud de la France.

Answer (score 0):

J'ai une amie qui emploie continuellement « comment dirais-je » mais aussi le « euh » car elle cherche continuellement ses mots. Il est vrai que c'est relativement fatiguant et même stressant d'entendre dans une longue conversation à tout bout de champ « comment dirais-je » et « euh ».

Comment: Ceci ne répond pas à la question. FL n'est pas un forum de discussion, mais un site de questions/réponses sur la langue française. Merci de lire la [rubrique d'aide](https://french.stackexchange.com/help).